# change data in SQL

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I´ve created a table in SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    Username String, 
    Countdown double, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

Now I want to change the `Countdown` - field.

```
try {
    final int i = 10; //my new var, which should saved in databank
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(""); //Dont know what to write in SQL here
    ps.executeUpdate();
} catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Example : Imagine my field with the field Username *"example"* has the `Countdown` 11 and now I want to change this value to 10.

Comment: [`UPDATE data SET Countdown = 10 WHERE Username = 'example';`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Comment: Step 1: **Learn SQL**. Any SQL tutorial will teach you the `UPDATE` statement very early on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a prepared statement, you need to "prepare" your query first, then inject the values. More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

First, you need an [UPDATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) query.

```
String updateStatement =
        "UPDATE data" +
        "SET Countdown = ? " +
        "WHERE Username = ?";
```

Then you can prepare your statement with:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(updateStatement);
```

And add your values with:

```
ps.setInt(1, 11);
ps.setString(2, "example");
```

And you're ready to go!

```
ps.executeUpdate();
```